# This field may not be blank notice at checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I only need Name and Email at checkout page so for that I'm using this WordPress plugin [Checkout Field Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/) to disable other fields but when I enter name and email and press place order its "This field may not be blank" and also at checkout page there is no Product Image Showing at checkout page.

[image]

[image: no Product Image Showing at checkout page]

p.s. I did researched for the solution from my side but didn't found any.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61752966/1593365 Yes, this is already answered by myself which is similar to what you are facing. For my solution, you don't need a plugin hook is enough.

Comment: Bro, also at checkout page product image is not showing https://i.ibb.co/mTG8qVz/Capture.png

Comment: Not showing means inspect the page and find the URL in the `img` tag and find that URL in the networks tab to check whether you received 200 or 404 or 403 as HTTP status.

Comment: in search result I don't get this url but at inspect element I do get imgae url

Comment: Brother, I appreciate your time and kindness that you are helping.

Comment: Ok, open that image URL in new tab and confirm that image is loading as you expected or not.

Comment: yes it is loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218153/discussion-between-gvgvgvijayan-and-sachin).